# Is it legal to use Disney World movies as educational material for online paid classes?

Tags: copyright, online, legal-education

I have read on the Internet that certain educational enterprises are permitted to use video material in a legal way. I was wondering if the case of paid online classes would be one of them, either by buying a special license or without it.